# Entity Framework always adds two records in the tables

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm implementing an ASP.NET Core 3.1 app. I have implemented following code to insert record in SQL Server database via EF Core but each time I save data, it inserts two records in `PersonRequester` and `Requester` table. I appreciate if anyone suggests me how I can prevent reinserting records.

```
Requester ap = new Requester();

ap.Address = RequesterViewModel.Requestervm.Address;
ap.RequesterType = RequesterViewModel.Requestervm.RequesterType;
ap.Description = RequesterViewModel.Requestervm.Description;
ap.Name = RequesterViewModel.Requestervm.Name;

var pa = new PersonRequester()
             {
                 BirthCertificateNo = RequesterViewModel.personRequestervm.BirthCertificateNo,
                 IssuePlace = RequesterViewModel.personRequestervm.IssuePlace,
                 NationalCode = RequesterViewModel.personRequestervm.NationalCode,

                 Requester = ap
             };

using (var context = new DBContext())
{
    context.PersonRequester.Attach(pa);

    try
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}

public partial class Requester
{
        public Requester()
        {
            PersonRequester = new HashSet<PersonRequester>();
        }

        public int RequesterId { get; set; }
        public int RequesterType { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual EntityType RequesterTypeNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PersonRequester> PersonRequester { get; set; }
}

public partial class PersonRequester
{
        public int RequesterId { get; set; }
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public int RequesterType { get; set; }
        public string NationalCode { get; set; }
        public string BirthCertificateNo { get; set; }
        public string IssuePlace { get; set; }

        public virtual Requester Requester { get; set; }
        public virtual EntityType RequesterTypeNavigation { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue. In my local build the `context.ChangeTracker.Entries()` contained one-one `Requester` and `PersonRequester` entries, and the `SaveChanges()` also resulted in a single entry in these database tables (in MS SQL db, with ASP.NET Core / EF Core 5.0). Too bad, because  it sounded like an interesting problem. :) So I suspect the issue originates from somewhere else. Or version-dependent?

Comment: Obvious, but: Have you confirmed with a breakpoint that this code is only triggered one time?

Comment: Also, where is the PK on the PersonRequester entity?  There is a RequesterId for the Requester reference. This looks like a many-to-many joining table which seems like a rather odd way to insert data. This should be using `Add` as well rather than `Attach`. `Attach` is intended for re-attaching existing detached entities.